# How can I unit test HandleUnknownAction() of an ASP.NET MVC Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tdd

I have the following HandleUnknownAction set on my base controller class:

```
protected override void HandleUnknownAction(string action)
{
    Response.Redirect("/");
}
```

How can I unit test that? Another point, is that way to handle the unknown action correct? Seems that calling RedirectToAction() would be more correct but the HandleUnknownAction doesn't have a return value.

The far I could get to test that is:

```
[Test]
public void TestHandleUnknownAction()
{
    ctroler.ActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ctroler.ControllerContext, "unknown");
}
```

I'm stuck at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a need to test that HandleUnknownAction is invoked when a controller is missing an action. We trust the framework to handle that. So we can test the implementation by calling HandleUnknownAction directly with the mocking framework [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/). Should also be possible with [Rhino Mocks](http://ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx).

```
public void TestHandleUnknownAction()
{
    Mock<ControllerContext> cc = new Mock<ControllerContext>
                                           (MockBehavior.Strict);
    cc.Expect(c => c.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/"));

    TestHelperController controller = new TestHelperController();
    controller.ControllerContext = cc.Object;

    controller.InvokeUnknownAction("test");
}
```

Where TestHelperController makes the HandleUnknownAction accessible:

```
public class TestHelperController : RealController
{
    public void InvokeUnknownAction(string action)
    {
        this.HandleUnknownAction(action);
    }
}
```

Comment: Got your point about calling HandleUknownAction, but what is that Mock object magic behind? Where this object come from? That Expect function is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Forgot to mention Moq, sorry. Updated the answer with a link.

Comment: Man, that Moq library is a dream, you got it, all the reputation belongs to you!

Answer (score 1):

That's fine for a simple Response.Redirect but that unit test code will not work if you want to do something more complicated like rendering an error view:

```
// TODO - Put some stuff into ViewData or a model
View("Error").ExecuteResult(Me.ControllerContext)
```